# python script runs in interpreter but not from command line

Tags: pexpect

Basically,

```
$ python script.py
```

doesn't do the job.

```
$ python -c 'execfile( "script.py" )'
```

doesn't do the job

```
$ python
>>>
```

pasting the commands here does the job

```
>>> execfile( "script.py")
```

also does the job.

Script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn( 'command' )
child.sendline( 'y' )
```

Comment: can you post more information such as whether you are running in administrator mode on windows / linux, has your environment variables been set correctly for python etc?

Comment: Thanks for helping. Am a py noob. Am not root and installed pip and expect in my own ~/python. What was happening was that command was getting killed after the python script exited. Luckily, found something that worked. Thanks!

Comment: As @Dean219 hit on above, your path variable is most likely the reason you can't run python scripts from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn( '/bin/bash -c "command"' )
child.sendline( 'y' )
child.interact()
child.sendcontrol( 'z' )
child.sendline( 'bg' )
```

Comment: The problem I have is that this script persists even after the application launched using the script (which is a big GUI app) is exited. Is there any way to ensure this script terminates when the main app exits? Thanks

Comment: In expect (command line one), after the last "automation" (the last send) I usually either do an ```interact``` so I'll start using the spawned app or do an ```expect eof``` in order to wait for the process to end.